# Mqseries queuemanager Name error(Reason code 2058)

Tags: perl, ibm-mq

---

I am trying to connect to my local queue by using cpan mqseries lib through perl script, in solaris environment.When i am executing my script it is giving Reson code as 2058.which means Queuemanager name error.

I have done following thing to analysis this issue,but still getting the reson code 2058.

1)Stop and started the queue manager.
2)checked the queuemanager name in my code.
3)sucessfully put and get the message in my queue by using amqget and amqput command,but it not working with my script.

Could anybody please help me in this,what kind of environment i have to set or any configuration setting i am missing.

```
my $qm_name = "MQTEST";

my $compCode = MQCC_WARNING;

my $Reason =   MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;


my $Hconn = MQCONN($qm_name,
                         $compCode,
                         $Reason,
                        ) || die "Unable to Connect to Queuemanager\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running to this issue?

> "By default, the MQSeries module will try to dynamically determine
>   whether or not the localhost has any queue managers installed, and if
>   so, use the "server" API, otherwise, it will use the "client" API.
>        This will Do The Right Thing (tm) for most applications, unless you want to connect >directly to a remote queue manager from a host
>   which is running other queue managers locally. Since the existence of
>   locally installed queue managers will result in the use of the
>   "server" API, attempts to connect to the remote queue managers will
>   fail with a Reason Code of 2058."